# No AVPlayer Delegate? How to track when song finished playing? Objective C iPhone development

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I've looked around but I can't find a delegate protocol for the `AVPlayer class`. What gives?

I'm using its subclass, `AVQueuePlayer`, to play an array of `AVPlayerItems`, each loaded from a URL. Is there any way I can call a method when a song finishes playing? Notably at the end of the queue?

And if that's not possible, is there any way I could call a method when the song STARTS playing, after buffering? I'm trying to get a loading icon in there but it turns the icon off before the music actually begins, even though it's after the `[audioPlayer play]` action.

Answer (score 156):

Yes, the AVPlayer class does not have a delegate protocol like the AVAudioPlayer. You need to subscribe to notifications on an AVPlayerItem. You can create an AVPlayerItem using the same URL that you would otherwise pass to `-initWithURL:` on AVPlayer.

```
-(void)startPlaybackForItemWithURL:(NSURL*)url {

    // First create an AVPlayerItem
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    // Subscribe to the AVPlayerItem's DidPlayToEndTime notification.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];

    // Pass the AVPlayerItem to a new player
    AVPlayer* player = [[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem] autorelease];

    // Begin playback
    [player play]

} 

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    // Will be called when AVPlayer finishes playing playerItem
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use `itemDidFinishPlaying:`, e.g. with colon. From `NSNotificationCenter` documentation: _The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only one argument (an instance of `NSNotification`)._

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic Thanks for the note - I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Add a KVO observer to the player's status or rate:

```
- (IBAction)go {
   self.player = .....
   self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionStop;
   [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:0]; 
}

- (void)stopped {
    ...
    [self.player removeObserver:self]; //assumes we are the only observer
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == 0) {
        if(player.rate==0.0) //stopped
            [self stopped];
    }
    else
        [super observeVal...];
}
```

So basically, that's it.

Disclaimer: I wrote that in here so I didn't check if the code was good. ALSO I never used AVPlayer before but it should be about right.

Comment: How to remove @"rate"  observer?

Comment: I was told in an edit that I need to observe rate for sure. adapted

Comment: A problem with this approach is that it will think a pause is the end of the music. Rate at pause is zero as it would be at end.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3** - I add an observer to `AVPlayerItem` every time I add a video to the player:

```
func playVideo(url: URL) {
  let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVURLAsset(url: someVideoUrl))
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
  self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
  self.player.play()
}

func playerItemDidPlayToEndTime() {
  // load next video or something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information in the Apple docs [AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW8) (look for the monitoring playback section). It appears to be mainly through KVO so you may wish to brush up on that if you are not too familiar (there is a guide for that to [Key Value Observing ProgrammingGuide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i).

Comment: Thanks, first I got it working by monitoring the time through KVO but then I implemented the AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification since it's cleaner and less processor-intensive.

Comment: A bit of a crazy mix of NSNotificationCenter, KVO and block-based in there. Make your mind up Apple!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one, and it works:

```
_player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_playingAudio.url]];
CMTime endTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(_playingAudio.duration, 1);
timeObserver = [_player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:endTime]] queue:NULL usingBlock:^(void) {
    [_player removeTimeObserver:timeObserver];
    timeObserver = nil;
    //TODO play next sound
}];
[self play];
```

where `_playingAudio` is my custom class with some properties and `timeObserver` is `id` ivar.