# How to get interruption start/end events for AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, avplayer, avaudiosession, interruption

I am playing audio files with `AVPlayer`.
I implemented `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification`.

```
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *errorInAudio   = nil;
    [session setActive:YES error:&errorInAudio];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

It works fine when an interruption came while the app is in foreground(like voice control).
But I made the app in background mode and opened the iPod player and start playing. Its interruption is not getting called at that time and even when my app entered foreground.
What may be the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `AVAudioPlayer` you can conform to `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` then you can implement methods like `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`

More methods listed in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the delegate of AVAudioPlayer. But I would like to know whether there is any way to implement this using AVPlayer. Can you suggest an idea.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with AVPlayer but this SO question covers the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837002/no-avplayer-delegate-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing-objective-c-iphon

Comment: Anyway I am changing my AVPlayer to AVAudioPlayer. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Haha well glad I could help. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: This does not work if you are trying to stream audio from the web.

Answer (score 1):

To get notified when `AVPlayer` is interrupted in background you can listen notification of the AudioSession

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerStopped) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```