# How do I get current playing time and total play time in AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: ios, avqueueplayer

Is it possible get playing time and total play time in AVQueuePlayer? If yes, how can I do this?

**What i have tried so far** :

```
CMTime currentTime = [self.myAVQueuePlayerObject currentTime];
```

But it is returning the currently played duration of the currentItem located in the Queue.

**What i want to achieve ?**

I want to get the currentTime Played with respect to all the items present in the AVQueue Player , how can i do that ?

Any Help is Highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `AVQueuePlayer` is inherited by `AVPlayer`...

Playing Time:

```
float currentTime = queuePlayer.currentTime;
```

Total Play Time:

Use KVO to observe the events of `AVQueuePlayer` (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837002/no-avplayer-delegate-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing-objective-c-iphon)), and calculate the total play time of your queue yourself.

For total time of current playing song, you can use:

```
float duration = queuePlayer.duration;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, `float currentTime = queuePlayer.currentTime;` will this line return the currentTime of the track that is being played currently or will this return the currentTime as comparison with all the items present in the Queue ?

Comment: `currentTime` is current time of current playing item (song).

Comment: Ok, so if i want to get the current Time with respect to All the items in the AVQueuePlayer then how will i manage to get it ? I am updating the question too

Comment: You can calculate the played duration with a `float` variable. Just add them up.