# How to tell when AVPlayer has loaded a video completely

Tags: ios, avplayer, nsurl, avasset

I need to know when `AVPlayer` has completely finished loading a video asset so there is no video lag/freeze. When I begin to play the video, it plays half way through and then freezes. If I exit and open again, it plays the rest of the video and will repeat the video smoothly. First I load the asset:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[tracksKey] completionHandler:
 ^{

     // Completion handler block.
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    ^{
                        NSError *error;
                        AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];

                        if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {
                               AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
                               // Set Key-Observers
                        }
                      });
       }];
```

---

I set three key-observers on the item and set the player with the item

```
 [item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"
                                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&ItemStatusContext];

[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"
                                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&playbackLikelyToKeepUp];

[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferFull"
                                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:&playbackBufferFull];

 self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
```

---

Next, I check to see if the player/item are ready to play and also if playBackLikelyToKeepUp is true.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

   if ((context == &ItemStatusContext) || (context == &playbackLikelyToKeepUp)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       if ((self.player.currentItem != nil) &&
                           ([self.player.currentItem status] == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) && (self.player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == YES) && (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)) {
                           NSLog(@"CALLED TO PLAY");
                           [self prerollVideoPlayer];
                       }
                       else {
                           [self.spinner startAnimating];
                       }
                   });
    return;
   }
   else if (context == &playbackBufferFull){
    if ((self.player.currentItem.playbackBufferFull) && (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)) {
        NSLog(@"Full Play");
        [self prerollVideoPlayer];
    }

    return;
   }

   [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object
                       change:change context:context];
   return;
}
```

---

Finally I call `preroll` and begin playing when finished.

```
-(void)prerollVideoPlayer{
   [self.player prerollAtRate:1.0 completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
        [self.spinner stopAnimating];
        [self.player play];
    }
   }];
}
```

But I still get video lag and the `AVPlayer` freezes half way through. Im trying to find out when the player has fully loaded, or at least enough so the video can begin without a pause halfway through. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried prerollAtRight higher than 1.0 to force it preload more content?

Comment: @beyowulf Just tried it...no luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837002/no-avplayer-delegate-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing-objective-c-iphon

have you checked?