# How Do you Play an Ad after a Video has finished playing in tvOS?

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, applovin

So I can video to play when you click on the thumbnail  but if I attach the ad to it, the ad will play over the video. how do I wait to play the ad after?

```
func playVideo(){

    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: String(vid))!)
    player?.play()

    if(ALInterstitialAd.isReadyForDisplay()){
        ALInterstitialAd.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Present the ad once the `AVPlayer` has finished playing, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605261/2108547

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to register for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`?

Just add

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
```

when you play your video and implement the `itemDidFinishPlaying:` method when you need to present your advertising. Something like this:

```
func playVideo(){
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: String(vid))!)
    player?.play()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
}

func itemDidFinishPlaying(notification : NSNotification){
    if(ALInterstitialAd.isReadyForDisplay()){
        ALInterstitialAd.show()
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
}
```