# AVPlayer recognize Playback end

Tags: swift, avplayer

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: jsonSession[indexPath.row].link)!
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        player.allowsExternalPlayback = true
        player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
```

this is my code and i try to recommend if a playback end, to play the next movie :-)

Comment: You can use a notification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605261/2108547

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to use [`AVQueuePlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/)

```
let items:[AVPlyerItem] = []
for session in jsonSession {
  guard let url = NSURL(string:session.link) else { continue }
  let item = AVPlayerItem(URL:url)
  items.add(item)
}
let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
//now you have the player, do what you were doing before
```

Second option is to do [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW18) on `AVPlayer`. It could do something like

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: jsonSession[indexPath.row].link)!
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
NSNotiicationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector#Selector(ViewController.itemDidFinishPlaying), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player.currentItem)
//I assume your ViewController class has a method called itemDidFinishPlaying
```

These are rough code samples, interpret as required.

Comment: What error? These are written on top of the head, didn't check for compile error, but it should give you an idea on how to do this