# How we can access the native event controls of AVPlayerViewController in swift using notification or else. Like - play, pause or progress value?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

How we access AVPlayerViewController's native event controls to track the current duration of the video or pause or resume and play or stop the video to get the callback.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837002/no-avplayer-delegate-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing-objective-c-iphon it should help explain how to listen for playback events

Comment: I want to get the event like pause and resume of AVPlayerViewController's. Using Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime we will notify when the video is finished. Let me know if you have any other link.