# How can I save the last paused time in an AVPlayer, and seek to it in another storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, swift5

I'm new to xCode/swift so please forgive my inexperience. I have a ViewController where my viewers can listen to some audio playback. The playback is accessed like this when the player clicks a play button:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: RoundButton)
{
    self.clickedButton = sender
    guard let url = sender.url else {
        return
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player
    
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }

}
```

I got this code from another StackOverflow question, so I don't *completely* understand it. My goal is to be able to save the URL and the last played time so that the user can minimize the app, or navigate to a different screen, and then be able to click a "continue listening" button which will pull up another AVPlayer with the last used URL. This "continue listening" AVPlayer will then seek to the last played time.

I know that I need to observe the first AVPlayer somehow, so that when it is paused, stopped, or put in the background, I save the currentTime to a NSUserDefault (I think?). I also need to save the URL, because there are many different URLs that the user could click on.

I tried doing this, and besides not being able to figure out the observation, I also couldn't figure out the type inconsistencies present with NSUserDefault. I tried to retrieve URL NSDefault value as a String after setting it, but when I went to cast the String to a URL using URL(string: lastPlayedURL), xCode complained about "Cannot convert type Data? to expected type String".

My issue with using other StackOverflow questions to solve my problem is that I don't understand where to put the code blocks. Where do I create the observer? Because xCode did not seem happy when I created it inside the body of "buttonClicked".

Thank you for listening to my rambling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `UserDefaults` seem appropriate to store the URL in. Use [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414194-set) to do that.

To observe the player you need to use an `AVPlayerItem`. Here's [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43673079/1971013) that shows that.

About your general issues with Xcode (note the capitalisation) and Swift language, I'm afraid these are things you need to work through yourself by reading/watching tutorials/documentation. Then when you find detailed issues, post your code here and ask.

Good luck and have fun!